# Any Windows Device Manager equivalents?

Tags: drivers, battery, devices

My laptop (asus x511mav) apparently has a non-functional battery as of a few months ago.

I installed Ubuntu on it yesterday because it was my secondary computer but I love Ubuntu and would like to use it as a laptop again (wireless).

Many guides online say to update the device drivers for the battery to (hopefully) fix it. Is there any way to do this from Ubuntu? (My Windows environment is very slow)

Sorry guys, I'm a newbie at this

Comment: Can you specify which version do you use? 
Can you be more specific, one time you mention the windows environment and another time you mention battery. 
If you want to optimize battery usage you can use TLP http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

Comment: Did you mean your battery is not working (not charging, not working when the computer is not connected to the mains, ...), or that ubuntu does not sees the battery or battery level?

Comment: There are no specific battery drivers in Linux (nor in Windows either I think). And no, you can't really update drivers in Windows from Ubuntu. You can turn off devices and services which increase power usage, but you can't really 'fix' the battery through software. If the battery has come to the point where it needs to be replaced, then the best thing to do is replace it.

Comment: My battery isn't charging.